# sql query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables

```
post
-------------
post_id
cat_id
posts

post_category
-------------
cat_id
cat_name

users
------------- 
user_id
user_name

user_category_map
-------------
user_id
cat_id
```

I want all posts added by all users in all post categories

I have written this query

```
 SELECT posts 
  FROM post p, users u, user_category_map ucm 
 WHERE p.cat_id = ucm.cat_id 
   AND ucm.user_id = u.user_id
```

but I am getting repeated posts. Is my table structure correct and normalized properly. I am not able to correctly grab the logic. Is the join I put is correct?

Comment: Where is your `user_id` to `post_id` mapping?

Comment: It seems that you have many users mapped to one category so POST to USER is ONE to MULTIPLE relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design does not look correct. Instead of a reference table for user_category, you should have a reference table for user_post. In current scenario, if same user adds multiple posts for same category, you will end up having duplicate rows in user_category_map

Comment: Hi Kamal, Thanks for your reply. So what you think should I create a separate table for post and user mapping or just add user Id in post table. What is better?

Comment: I don't think you need a user_category_map. If you create a user_post_map that will give you a relation between user_id and post_id. Post table already has category info (cat_id), so no need to have a separate table for that

Answer (score 3):

Here you received the full cartesian product of all tables, and filter it by " p.cat_id = ucm. cat_id and ucm.user_id = u.user_id" condition.
Query like this typically converted to optimized join versions - merge, nested loop, index or hash join.

During cartesian product A*B*C every row from A will be repeat B*C times.

Your query "all posts added by all users in all post categories" is

```
select * from post
```

Comment: But as per the table design, there can exist posts by anonymous users i.e. without an entry in users table. In that case, your query may return the posts with no user relation.

Comment: As I can understand source post, required ALL posts from ALL users (with anonymous too)